# Send value of Spinner to Public Static variable - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, spinner

so .. I have two Activities ,where on the `SecondActivity` I have a Spinner , and the item selected from this spinner , must be storage at a Variable public static , where at `TerceiraActivity` I can get the variable manipulate.

Theses are the activities.

"**SecondActivity**"

```
    package br.exemplosqlite;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

    import org.w3c.dom.Text;

    public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

public static String mahone = "atemais";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        //referencia a Spinner
        //Spinner coligada;

        //final TextView nome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvNome);
        //final TextView sobrenome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvSobrenome);
        //final Spinner pday = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        final Spinner spcoligada = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.coligada);






        //spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayAdapter adaptercoligada= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.coligada, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spcoligada.setAdapter(adaptercoligada);



        Button ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnok);







        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //chamada para a nova Activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, TerceiraActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("coligada", spcoligada.getSelectedItem().toString());


                //intent.putExtra("nomePessoa", nome.getText().toString());
                //intent.putExtra("sobrenomePessoa", sobrenome.getText().toString());
                //intent.putExtra("day", pday.getSelectedItem().toString());

                public String pcoligada="";








                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
       }
```

This is the "**TerceiraActivity**"

```
package br.exemplosqlite;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TerceiraActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_terceira);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //String parametro = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("nomePessoa");
    //String psobrenome = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("sobrenomePessoa");
    //String ppday = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("day");

    String pcoligada = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("coligada");


    //TextView nome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvNome);
    //TextView sobrenome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvSobrenome);
    TextView coligadas = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spvcoligada);


    //nome.setText("Olá " + parametro + ", Tem de fazer a barba " );
    coligadas.setText("coliga escolhida : " +pcoligada);
}
  }
```

Comment: I think you want `getStringExtra`, not `getSerializableExtra`...

Comment: Your code seems to be fine.  You pass the right value as a parameter to the `Intent` and then start the corresponding `Activity`. What's the problem?

Comment: i wanna make the "pcoligada" public , so , i'll pass this variable to my BD.class , could u help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `getSerializableExtra` to `getStringExtra`,

If you want to make **pcoligada** public than declare as global variable,

Change code to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, TerceiraActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("coligada", spcoligada.getSelectedItem().toString());

            //intent.putExtra("nomePessoa", nome.getText().toString());
            //intent.putExtra("sobrenomePessoa", sobrenome.getText().toString());
            //intent.putExtra("day", pday.getSelectedItem().toString());

            startActivity(intent);
```

`public String pcoligada = "";` // take global variable , you can take it as static variable also to access from other class

Now `onCreate()` method of another activity;

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //String parametro = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("nomePessoa");
    //String psobrenome = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("sobrenomePessoa");
    //String ppday = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("day");

    pcoligada = intent.getStringExtra("coligada");

    //TextView nome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvNome);
    //TextView sobrenome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvSobrenome);
    TextView coligadas = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spvcoligada);


    //nome.setText("Olá " + parametro + ", Tem de fazer a barba " );
    coligadas.setText("coliga escolhida : " +pcoligada);
```

Comment: Just curious. String implements Serializable, so why would it need changed?

Comment: because i use it this way, no more reasons

Comment: Hey Amit , my code is working , the only think that i want is change "pcoligada" to public , so i'll pass this variable to my BD.class , can u help me ?

Comment: Amit , i change the SecondActivity , please see if is correct.

Comment: I want , that when select item from spinner at SecondActivity , this value of spinner , must be public static , because , i wanna put this value to a other Activity called "BD.class " or , use the value in any Acitivitys